# Django REST Framework: Using same queryset from two different URLs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two ModelViewSets for `Groups` and `Memberships`:

```
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsGroupOwnerOrSuperuser,)
    ...


class MembershipViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Membership.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MembershipSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsMemberOrSuperuser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        # do some stuff including filter query by group
        group_id = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('group_id', None)
        ...
        return queryset
```

In `MembershipViewSet`, `get_queryset` allows your query to filter by group_id, to get members associated with a particular group.

In the `GroupViewSet`, I want to also allow filtering by groups at the URL `/groups/{pk}/memberships`:

```
    @link()
    def memberships(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

However I don't want to break DRY by replicating `get_queryset` code from `MembershipsViewSet`. So something like the below code, though it doesn't work:

```
@link()
def memberships(self, request, pk=None):
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # The following doesn't work because QUERY_PARAMS is immutable
    self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.update({'group_id':pk})
    mems = MembershipViewSet.get_queryset(self)
    mems = MembershipSerializer(mems, many=true, context={'request': request})
    return Response(mems.data)
```

So the question is: how do I redirect or at least re-use code for a query that should return identical results from two different DRF URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but you could replace this line

```
# The following doesn't work because QUERY_PARAMS is immutable
self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.update({'group_id':pk})
```

with

```
self.kwargs['group_id'] = pk
```

and then in your **get_queryset** you can take the group id the same way.

```
group_id = self.kwargs.get('group_id', None)
```

This is how I usually do it, and it works for me. Hope this helps.